# Using df.astype(str) changes Dataframe into single elements

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a piece of code that works perfectly on one computer, but when I try to run it on my home computer, the `astype()` function acts weirdly:

```
df = read_table('TMinput.csv',sep=',')

df = df.astype(str)
```

The dataframe now looks like this:

```
  Unnamed: 0 Name Type Lifetime Budget Daily Budget Start Date End Date Segment
ID  \
0          L    T    n               8            7          4        4  
 n
1          C    T    W               n            3          4        4
 5
2          C    T    W               n            6          4        4
 5
3          C    T    W               n            3          4        4
 5
4          C    T    W               n            6          4        4
 5
5          C    T    W               n            3          4        4
 5
6          C    T    W               n            6          4        4
```

Don't know why exactly this is happening...

Comment: do you have similar versions of python / Pandas on both computers? similar OS?

Comment: same OS, same version of python.  Not sure about pandas version.  Either way, I don't think pandas should be deleting most of the Dataframe data when you try to change type to string

Comment: this changed somewhat in 0.11/0.12 so the pandas version is important to know